# Why arraysize is identified as zero in my mex code?

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mex

I have a mex function and I'm using it in matlab with the following command (interface):

Matsize = 30555

```
Fv_calc(:,2) = mx_solve_quadratic(QuadraticCoefficients,MatSize);
```

The gateway function is as follows:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    int *arraysizePtr = NULL;
    arraysizePtr = (int *)mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    int arraysize = *arraysizePtr;
    float *inMatrix = NULL;
    inMatrix = (float *)mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    const float a = 1; /* coefficient for x^2 is always 1*/
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(arraysize, 1, mxSINGLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    float *out = (float *)mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    float x0; /* the smaller root */
    float x1; /* the bigger root */
    int fOutput = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arraysize; i++)
    {
        fOutput = gsl_poly_solve_quadratic(a, inMatrix[i], inMatrix[i + arraysize], &x0, &x1);
        out[i] = (x1 > 0 ? x1 : 0);
    }
}
```

Everything is true because I have run the code before and now I have just made a slight change.
I really don't understand why arraysize is identified as `0` when running the mex code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mxGetPr` seems to return a `double *` from what I can find online.

(https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetpr.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop)

Casting and assigning it to `int *arraysizePtr` will cause the `double` data to be interpreted as `int` when accessed trough `*arraysizePtr`, yielding nonsense.

Comment: OK, the the code should be written as follows: `double *arraysizePtr = NULL;
 arraysizePtr = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
 const int arraysize = (int)*arraysizePtr;`